# Angular JS unable to display a field when the result is retrieved from salesforce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce, visualforce

I have used AngularJS while developing a visual force page and was trying to create a record under a custom object, I could see that the Salesforce controller is returning the ID to javascript callback function and am using

```
$scope.lblMsg={value:result['message']}
```

inside the success condition but I was unable to populate that into a label field and label field isn't displayed, whereas when I use

```
document.getElementById('lblMsg').innerHTML=result['message'];
```

I was able to display the message.

Can you please suggest what might be the mistake using AngularJS ? and also specify any effective solution to perform the task with AngularJS.

Please find the link below where the above form is hosted

http://ganeshforce-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/

Comment: In case of angular, whats `lblMsg` , is it `ng-model` for the `input` tag whose id is `lblMsg`??

Comment: @Sourabh- lblMsg is label id and ng-model="lblMsg.value" which is given in the parent element div

Comment: Can you post the relevant html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `$scope.lblMsg={value:result['message']}` inside a callback fro ma 3rd party api, like salesforce instead of a normal $http call? If 'yes', then you should consider wrapping that in an $apply block or an $applyAsync one, otherwise Angular won't know about that update.

Comment: worked like a charm, that was a wonderful suggestion, thank you for the help, really was waiting for an answer from a long time.

Answer (score -1):

I think your label looks like

```
  <label id="lblMsg"><label>
```

that's why you can get the label element using 'id' attribute like

```
  document.getElementById('lblMsg');
```

If you want to achieve this result in angular style, your html code should be

```
 <label>{{lblMsg}}<label>
```

and your controller code should be

```
 $scope.lblMsg=result['message'];
```

Comment: In JS `.value` is for `input` and not `label`

Comment: sorry Sourabh it was a typo mistake @Sourabh

Comment: @venkatasubbaraokoppolu. NP. You can upvote this answer then as I can't since my vote is locked.

Comment: this is not my mistake @sourabh... i haven't use value attribute there... i just let him know about how to bind the model and view in angular